# GD image resize (w/ CI) with huge (6000+ wide) images

Tags: codeigniter, gd, php, ram

I have an application that resizes uploaded images, using the Codeigniter image manipulation class and GD.

However, the client needs to be able to resize super-large images, 6000px or higher. I have memory issues when this occurs.

My question is in two parts- is there a way to calculate how much memory is required, via the dimensions of the image?

Is there a less memory intensive option for resizing these images, which appear to go over 250MB for each action.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

GD always works on the uncompressed image; this is where the memory is used.  You can estimate the memory consumption as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527532/reasonable-php-memory-limit-for-image-resize).  For more information, see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661/efficient-jpeg-image-resizing-in-php) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684396/should-gd-need-so-much-memory-when-resizing).